# Firebase requests denied after page refresh on Angular Fire

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I've just updated project dependencies, both angular fire, firebase and angular and noticed, that user loses permission to make firebase requests.
When user logs in, everything works fine, but after he refreshes the page, he receives next error on all firebase subscriptions:

```
Error: permission_denied at /settings/PERSONAL_OFFER_ACTIVATION_MINUTES: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

Here's example of my service with login and some requests:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ) { }

login(firebaseToken: string) {
 return this.afAuth.signInWithCustomToken(firebaseToken);
}

async loginFb() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    const result = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
    return result;
  }

  async loginGoogle() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    const result = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
    return result;
  }
  
   getPersonalOfferTimer(): Observable<number> {
    return this.db.object(`settings/PERSONAL_OFFER_ACTIVATION_MINUTES`).valueChanges() as Observable<number>;
  }
  
   getMovementsPurchaseTimeout(): Observable<number> {
    return this.db.object(`settings/PURCHASE_MOVEMENTS_TIMEOUT`).valueChanges() as Observable<number>;
  }
```

Basically, nothing specific and on previous versions everything worked fine without any issues. As far as I remember, user was automatically saved until he logs out and all requests were working properly. Now it seems like user isn't saved anymore. But I haven't found any description in version changes on firebase or angular fire that should handle that.

Previous versions was Angular 8, Firebase 5.5.8 and Angular Fire 5.1.0

Maybe someone came across same issue?

Answer (score 0):

So in my case I have found that firebase user is loaded a little bit later then other subscriptions triggered. Basically pushing all subscription through `afAuth.authState` will do the work. Not ideal, but a little example:

```
  getWebState(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.afAuth.authState
      .pipe(
        switchMap(_ =>
          this.db.object(`settings/BLOCK_WEB_GAME`)
            .valueChanges() as Observable<boolean>
        )
      )
  }
```

Gonna find a better realisation for this, since I doubt that switching from AuthState in every request is good approach, but, at least it's something.